# Slow performance reading teradata table in python

Tags: python, r, teradatasql

I'm trying to read a table from Teradata big it takes a lot of time.  My table has 5 millions of rows and 60 columns and it took 30 minutes to load in memory. I'm using teradatasql package, but the same table took 5 minutes to load in R with RJDBC package.

Python code (This take 30 minutes)

```py
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd

conn = teradatasql.connect(host=host, user=user_name, password=password, database=database)
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM big_table", conn)
```

R code (This take only 3 minutes)

```
library(RJDBC)

# teradata conecction
con_tera <- dbConnect(drv_tera, "jdbc:teradata://{ip_host}/DATABASE=DBI_MIN,DBS_PORT=1025",Sys.getenv("TERA_DB_USER"), Sys.getenv("TERA_DB_PASS"))

# create query
final_query <- 'select * from big_table'

# get data
dataset_caribu <- dbGetQuery(con_tera,final_query)
```

I tried to increase arraysize of cursor in python but it doesn't improve execution time much.

Answer (score 0):

pandas.read_sql is slower than using the teradatasql driver directly.

Here is a simple Python script that I used for testing 5 million rows and 60 columns with 80% non-NULL and 20% NULL column values:

```py
import pandas
import teradatasql
import time
with teradatasql.connect (host="whomooz", user="guest", password="please") as con:
 with con.cursor () as cur:
  cur.execute ("create volatile table voltab (" + ",".join ([ "c{} integer".format (n) for n in range (1, 61) ]) + ") on commit preserve rows")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select row_number() over (order by calendar_date) as c1 from sys_calendar.calendar qualify c1 <= 62500")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 62500 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 125000 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 250000 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 500000 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 1000000 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 2000000 from voltab")
  cur.execute ("insert into voltab(c1) select c1 + 4000000 from voltab where c1 <= 1000000")
  cur.execute ("update voltab set " + ",".join ([ "c{} = c1".format (n) for n in range (2, 49) ]))
  cur.execute ("select * from voltab")
  print ('beginning fetchall')
  dStartTime = time.time ()
  rows = cur.fetchall ()
  dElapsed = time.time () - dStartTime
  print ("fetchall took {} seconds, or {} minutes, and returned {} rows".format (dElapsed, dElapsed / 60, len (rows)))
  dStartTime = time.time ()
  df = pandas.read_sql ("select * from voltab", con)
  dElapsed = time.time () - dStartTime
  print ("read_sql took {} seconds, or {} minutes, and returned {} rows".format (dElapsed, dElapsed / 60, len (df)))
```

My results are:

```
fetchall took 638.6090559959412 seconds, or 10.64348426659902 minutes, and returned 5000000 rows
read_sql took 2293.84486413002 seconds, or 38.23074773550034 minutes, and returned 5000000 rows
```